# CKError when querying system field: rejected "Unknown Field 'createdAt'"

Tags: cloudkit, ckquery

I am sorting the `createdAt` system field like this:

```
query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)]
```

and get the following error:

> CKError 0x1c4447fb0: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2018); server message =
>   "Unknown field 'createdAt'"; uuid =
>   9C450848-2449-4892-93BC-C46363203042; container ID = "...

I am able to query and sort fields that I create in this manner. Anything different with a system field?
The field's index is sortable and queryable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `creationDate` for the key, instead. The meta keys in the CK dashboard vary slightly from the ones used for queries. Here's a list of meta keys:

```
recordID: CKRecordID
The unique ID of the record.

recordType: String
The app-defined string that identifies the type of the record.

creationDate: Date?
The time when the record was first saved to the server.

creatorUserRecordID: CKRecordID?
The ID of the user who created the record.

modificationDate: Date?
The time when the record was last saved to the server.

lastModifiedUserRecordID: CKRecordID?
The ID of the user who last modified the record.

recordChangeTag: String?
A string containing the server change token for the record.
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks!  Any idea why the meta keys are different than on the CK dashboard?

Comment: Glad to help. Not sure why the keys themselves are different. But I remember struggling with CloudKit predicates and sort descriptors enough to have created a list of actual keys at some point, and saved them to my Notes app. :)

The meta field labels in the /original/ CloudKit dashboard may have matched the keys, but it's been too long for me to remember.

Comment: @BrianHamm Why am I not able to access the filed using CKRecord.object(forKey:) when I try to access it using "createdAt" or "creationDate"? How would I access the value of the creationAt field?

Comment: @DanielBrower Meta field values should be accessed as a property. Try 
`myRecord.creationDate`

Comment: Wow this is just absurd..why in the dashboard I see "modifiedAt" and set it as "sortable" and then I have to use "modificationDate"?! BTW thanks you solved the issue.